# call javascript from server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

my button on server works on alertMsg() how ever doesnt work on playSelected()

my button on Html works on playSelected() and alertMsg()

anyone can figure out for me why?

**javascript**

```
function playSelected() {

    var a = "Video/" + document.getElementById("TextBox2").value + ".flv";

    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({

        flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",

        file: a,

        image: "jwplayer/preview.jpg"
    });
}


function alertMsg() {
    alert("testing123");
}
```

**button in html**

```
input type="button" runat="server" value="Click me!" onclick='playSelected()'
```

**button in server**

asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" text="call javascript" OnClientClick="playSelected(); return true;" UseSubmitBehaviour="false"

Comment: If you use `Attributes.Add()`, you should use 'onclick' rather than the 'onclientclick' that you use in the aspx markup.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" 
            OnClientClick='playSelected(); return true;' 
            UseSubmitBehaviour="false" />
```

Comment: ya,it is added and it is the same,button in my page doesn't work

Comment: remove onclick because it will cause a full postback

Comment: removed, doesnt work too, i can use button on server to call alertFunction() but it doesnt work on my playSelected()

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work", in particular: do you get any javascript errors? Also: what is the html for that button (do a 'view source'), do you see the correct javascript call there?

Comment: You don't need this anymore: Button2.Attributes.Add("OnClientclick", "playSelected()");.Also is not doing what you think it does, it should be "onclick" instead of "OnClientClick". Did you check UseSubmitBehaviour property?

Comment: Return false to avoid the full postback

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your java script is allowed on the clietn browser. Also do postbacks logic in your page_load event. I would rather create the Button on overriden CreateChildControls method of the page, and on overriden OnPreRender wireup my java script and register the script with ClientScriptManager method RegisterStartupScript. So that you can have nice page life cycle control.